Legend position in plotScores (Chemospec package)
I am working on infrared spectral data using the "Chemospec" package. I performed a PCA and now want to visualize the results, the function "plotScores" plots the PCA scores. I am trying to move the position of the legend but it stays in the top right corner.The function "plotScores" uses ggplot2 to visualize the data so I tried different ggplot position assignments but nothing changes.
This is the code I am using:
p <- plotScores(data_sample, pca, pcs = c(1,2), ellipse = "no", tol = 0.01, legendPos = "bottom")
p <- p & ggtitle(myt)
p <- p + theme_gray() 
p <- p + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
p


Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Could you please share some reproducible data using dput?

The issue is that the legend is not based on ggplot2s system of guides but added as a text annotation instead. But you can use the leg.loc= argument of plotScores to specify the position of the legend.
Using the default example from ?plotScores:
library("ChemoSpec")
library("ggplot2")
data(metMUD1)

pca <- c_pcaSpectra(metMUD1)
p <- plotScores(metMUD1, pca,
  pcs = c(1, 2), ellipse = "cls",
  tol = 0.05, leg.loc = "bottom"
)
p <- p + ggtitle("metMUD1 NMR Data")
p


